# On tableView Update - Image will extend ImageView bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to build a `UITableView` which cells are containing a `UIImageView` and a few `UILabels`.

Not in general but sometimes updating the list via `reloadData()`.
My table images conflict with `UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill` and clipping to bounds.

The cell will appear like this, extending it's edges.:

[image]

**These options are set for the image in `awakeFromNib`:**

```
self.miniImg.layer.cornerRadius = self.miniImg.frame.width/2 // Circular
self.miniImg.clipsToBounds = true
self.miniImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.miniImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

My idea was to try and fix this by clipsToBounds and masksToBounds. But it didn't work.

Comment: do you have height and width constraints set on the imageView?

Comment: yes, both are 64 pixels in auto layout @Kex